# loading the same jsp in different browsers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="<%=dRoles%>">
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=public/First.jsp">
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="<%=aRoles%>">      
      <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=public/Second.jsp">
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="<%=bRoles%>">  
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=public/Third.jsp">
</sec:authorize>
```

i am using spring security. 
on success of login, Startup.jsp is loaded (**default-target-url="/Startup.jsp**). i have above code in my Startup.jsp. i am using spring security tags.  consider user has access to all above 3 jsps. **The problem is ,  in IE7, First.jsp is loaded but in Other browsers Third.jsp is loaded**.
How can i display same jsp in both the browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: `content="0;url=public/Second.jsp">` Change that 0 to 1000 (or a number long enough to..) pull up the source of the rendered page as rendered in the problem browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you're in a situation where a user has roles in `dRoles` and also roles in `bRoles`, and your code thus sends two different meta refreshes to the browser.

First, don't use meta refresh, but use a real redirect or a forward (and that shouldn't be done in a JSP, but in a controller, filter or servlet).

If you really want to stay with a JSP solution, I guess something like this should work:

```
<c:set var="refreshSent" value="${false}"/>

<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="<%=dRoles%>">
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=public/First.jsp">
    <c:set var="refreshSent" value="${true}"/>
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="<%=aRoles%>">
    <c:if test="${!refreshSent}">      
        <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=public/Second.jsp">
        <c:set var="refreshSent" value="${true}"/>
    </c:if>
</sec:authorize>

<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="<%=bRoles%>">  
    <c:if test="${!refreshSent}">
        <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=public/Third.jsp">
        <c:set var="refreshSent" value="${true}"/>
    </c:if>
</sec:authorize>
```